# Sqoop export from hdfs to GreenPlum is not working

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, greenplum

I am trying to export data from hdfs location to Greenplum user defined schema (not default schema).

**Tried Sqoop Eval to check the connection.**

```
sqoop eval --connect "jdbc:postgresql://sample.com:5432/sampledb" --username sample_user --password xxxx --query "SELECT * FROM sample_db.sample_table LIMIT 3"
```

**Result:**
working fine

**Tried with `--schema` option**

```
/usr/bin/sqoop export --connect "jdbc:postgresql://sample.com:5432/sampledb" --username sampleuser --password samplepassword --table sample_table --schema sample_schema --export-dir=/sample/gp_export --input-fields-terminated-by ',' --update-mode allowinsert
```

**Result:**

```
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.3.6.0-3796/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
18/06/25 11:09:41 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.3.6.0-3796
18/06/25 11:09:41 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
18/06/25 11:09:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for export:
18/06/25 11:09:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --schema
18/06/25 11:09:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: sample_schema
18/06/25 11:09:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --export-dir=/sample/gp_export
18/06/25 11:09:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --input-fields-terminated-by
18/06/25 11:09:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: ,
18/06/25 11:09:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --update-mode
18/06/25 11:09:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: allowinsert
```

**Added extra `'--'` before `'--schema'` based on the sqoop documentation 
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html**

```
 /usr/bin/sqoop export --connect "jdbc:postgresql://sample.com:5432/sampledb" --username sampleuser --password samplepassword --table sample_table -- --schema sample_schema --export-dir=/sample/gp_export --input-fields-terminated-by ',' --update-mode allowinsert
```

**Result:**

```
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.3.6.0-3796/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
18/06/25 11:06:26 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.3.6.0-3796
18/06/25 11:06:26 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
Export requires an --export-dir argument or --hcatalog-table argument.
Try --help for usage instructions.
```

Could someone guide me on this. Thanks

Comment: You have an empty `--` which ends the parameters

Comment: Extra -- is expected as per sqoop documentation

Comment: I'm not able to find that documented for the export command

Comment: Please check the link posted in my original post and search for 'schema'

Comment: Refer 23.3.2 in the documentation

Comment: The schema goes at the very end of all the other arguments according to that

Comment: changing the position of -- schema is working. Like below  /usr/bin/sqoop export --connect "jdbc:postgresql://sample.com:5432/sampledb" --username sampleuser --password samplepassword --export-dir=/sample/gp_export --input-fields-terminated-by ',' --update-mode allowinsert --table sample_table -- --schema sample_schema

Comment: Though export is working fine, upsert operation is not yet supported in Postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @cricket_007 for clarification.

`--schema` argument should be last in the sqoop command. So below code is working.

```
    /usr/bin/sqoop export --connect "jdbc:postgresql://sample.com:5432/sampledb"  \ 
--username sampleuser --password samplepassword  \ 
--export-dir=/sample/gp_export --input-fields-terminated-by ','  \ 
--table sample_table -- --schema sample_schema
```

But `UPSERT` operations not supported in postgresSql. There is an open Jira ticket here.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1270

Answer (score 0):

After the `--export-dir` you don't need the `=` check out the example below. Another suggestion is to use `--verbose` when you run into these kinds of issues.

```
sqoop export --libjars /path/some.jar \
--connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://IP:1433;database=db' \
--username someName -password somePassword -m 10 \
--verbose --mysql-delimiters \
--export-dir /HDFS/Path/someFile.csv \
--table "RDBMSTABLENAME"
```